# Искажение русского текста, Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

Есть клиент и сервер на Java RMI. Клиент считывает текст с консоли через `Scanner.NextLine()` и вызывает удаленный объект сервера и передает ему этот текст. Сервер выводит текст, а там - кракозябра.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

На клиенте:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = scanner.nextLine();
ChatServerInt server = (ChatServerInt)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/RMIchat");
ChatClientInt client = new ChatClient("username");
server.print(text, client);
```

На сервере:

```
public void print(String text, ChatClientInt sender) throws RemoteException{    
    System.out.println(sender.getUserName()+" написал: ");  
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: Консоль клиента и сервера имеют одинаковую кодировку?

Comment: это в настройках ide смотреть? или консоли windows?

Comment: Смотря где и как вы их запускаете.

Comment: я запускаю jar файл через консоль windows

Comment: Если и сервер, и клиент запускаются в консоли Windows, то проблема возникать не должна. Покажите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено добавлением `System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(System.out, true, "Cp866"));`